# Watch new files in a directory with Qt

Tags: qt, qdir

In my case files permanently are being added into the directory. I need to read names of the files which have the most recently been added into the directory, that is only new files. I'm tracking the directory using *QFileSystemWatcher* class. But how after that can I choose only new files with *entryList* or another command?

I'm able to define a special name format based on a creation time and select the necessary ones afterwards or I could differ files from each other by their modification time directly and try to use some embedded filters. 
But the first way is too slow and I couldn't find the appropriate filter in Qt documentation for *QDir* class.

Comment: If files cannot be renamed, you can use `QSet` to remember old files.

Comment: Rather than use `QFileSystemWatcher` you might be better off using [`QFileSystemModel`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qfilesystemmodel.html).  Set the [root path](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qfilesystemmodel.html#setRootPath) to the directory of interest and listen for the various signals such as [`rowsInserted`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qabstractitemmodel.html#rowsInserted) etc.